# Retention period kinesis

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I developed application with Spark-streaming+Kinesis.
I started my app at 2015-10-30 and it works. I saw 
Today (2015-11-02) I restarted the application, and it began to handle 2015-11-02.
Why? Retention period?
In docs

**"You can increase the retention period up to 168 hours using the IncreaseRetentionPeriod operation"**

I tried increase with command as describe in docs

**aws kinesis increase-stream-retention-period --stream-name XXXX --retention-period-hours 160**

But

**usage: aws [options]   [parameters]
aws: error: argument operation: Invalid choice, valid choices are:
add-tags-to-stream                       | create-stream
delete-stream                            | describe-stream
get-records                              | get-shard-iterator
list-streams                             | list-tags-for-stream
merge-shards                             | put-record
put-records                              | remove-tags-from-stream
split-shard                              | wait
help**

What should I do for increase retention period???

WBR, Slava

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to update the aws cli that you are using. you're probably using an older version that does not know about the newer command option.

@az3's answer is also worth looking into to understand why you pick up processing where you currently do. (he explains the behavior and I tend to agree :) )

Comment: I agree, the increase & decrease retention period option is pretty new, the old binaries may not support it. Update aws-cli to use that commands.

Answer (score 0):

- I don't think it is related to retention period. If you are using Kinesis Client Library (KCL), you may be persisting the last worked position to DynamoDB. So if you stop and start your application, it will continue to work from the last known position.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/dev/kinesis-record-processor-ddb.html

- If you want to read all the previous data in a shard, you should update the checkpoint in DynamoDB to "TRIM_HORIZON".

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/dev/kinesis-record-processor-additional-considerations.html

- When application sees TRIM_HORIZON, it will read the first data (approximately ~23 hours 55 minutes before) in Kinesis Stream. You can find more about retention here;

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/dev/kinesis-extended-retention.html